# C# application to access data from PostgreSQL and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

What is the best way to go about accessing data from SQL Server and PostgreSQL databases in a single ASP.NET web application? I have a gridview that I would like to have columns of data from both databases. Any suggestions?

I have tried creating an ODBC driver on the SQL server with a linked server to PostgreSQL and then create a view selecting from both databases. I got many conversion errors which I don't know how to resolve and performance issues as well.

Comment: "Best" can only be defined by you. I guess you have 2 options, the linked server, as you've tried, and pulling data from 2 databases in your app. You need to decide which suits your circumstances, and then ask a question about any issues you have for example if you decide to go the linked server way you might ask a question about how to resolve the conversion errors.

Comment: I sort of gave up on linked server and was wondering if there are any other ideas out there. I really do think it's the best idea for my circumstances. The error I'm getting when trying to select from the linked server is The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "linkedServer" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "Column" (compile-time ordinal 2) of object ""Database"."schema"."tablename"" was reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISLONG" of 128 at compile time and 0 at run time.

Comment: You'd need to ask a new, complete question.

Comment: Yes, as explained by @Dale K, the best option should be chosen by you. each method has its own pros and cons. For instance, the method you already have tried has its own issues such as data type mismatch, slowness, etc. I guess you can avoid type mismatch issues if you use the method to access both databases from you applications and load data to your own objects before merging them.

Comment: The main issue I am having I think is with citext columns in postgres. When I try selecting in SQL I get that errror.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two contexts(Unit of Work), one for Sql Server and other for PostgreSql.

After that you need to create one repository to get data from sql server using the Unit of Work for Sql Server and the same thing for PostgreSql.

Create a service to call both repositories

then call both repositories and retrieve the data you need to create a class that will be populated with both returns from the repositories

something like this

SqlServer Repository

```
public class SqlRepository: ISqlRepository
{
    private readonly ISqlUoW _uow;

    public SqlRepository(ISqlUoW uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public async Task<EntityA> GetDataAsync()
    {
        return await _uow.Connection.QueryAsync<EntityA>("select field1,field2 FROM EntityA");
    }
}
```

PostgreSql Repository

```
public class PGRepository: IPGRepository
{
    private readonly IUoWPG  _uow;

    public PGRepository(IUoWPG uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public async Task<Entityb> GetDataAsync()
    {
        return await _uow.Connection.QueryAsync<EntityB>("select field1,field3 FROM EntityB");
    }
}
```

the Grid Data Class

```
public class GridData
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}
```

the Service

```
public class GridService : IGridService
{
    private readonly ISqlRepository _sqlRepository;
    private readonly IPGRepository _pgRepository;

    public GridService(ISqlRepository sqlRepository, IPGRepository pgRepository)
    {
        _sqlRepository = sqlRepository;
        _pgRepository = pgRepository;
    }

    public async Task<IList<GridData>> GetGridData()
    {
        var sqlData = await _sqlRepository.GetDataAsync();
        var pgData = await _pgRepository.GetDataAsync();

        var gridData = from sql in sqlData
                       join pg in pgData on sql.Field1 equals pg.Field1
                       select new GridData()
                       {
                           Field1 = sql.Field1,
                           Field2 = sql.Field2,
                           Field3 = pg.Field3
                       };

        return gridData;
    }
}
```

in this scenario the shared key between the tables is the property **Field1**

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. If I'm dealing with 34,000 rows in postgres to merge with the sql data would your approach be a performance issue? How would I merge them in c# with no joins available?

Comment: why dont send all this data to a Data Lake ?

Comment: Hmmm I'm not enough advanced for this